# How to install ROMs without ClockWorkMod in Huawei U8800

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing

I have official Huawei ROM installed on my U8800 (Android 2.3.5) and I want to try some custom ROMs like MIUI. So I researched and find out that I need to replace default `recovery.img` file in `/.cust_backup/image` with ClockWorkMod Recovery image file. After I replaced this file successfully tried to boot into Recovery using `reboot recovery` command (also tried pressing [VOL+]+[Power]) but my phone didn't flash CWM but started to reboot several times instead. After 2 or 3 reboots phone is starting normally without flashing CWM. Then I restored replaced `recovery.img` with my backed-up one and rebooted, default Recovery screen flashed with no problem. I used official CWM Recovery image (5.0.2.6) for U8800 and some other unofficial CWM images for U8800. But none of them worked. I could neither solve this problem nor find another way to install my ROM Zip from SDCARD. Does anyone know what can I do to solve these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of different Recovery images finally one of them worked. CWM 5.0.2.7 flashed successfully. People with the same problem can download the working recovery image file from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/genoandroid/files/recovery5.0.2.7_en_u8800.img/download)